# MySQL database update error for different language

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what is happening with my Website. I have a PHP website and to update the content I have an  Admin Panel and it is working fine for English but when I tried to update the content with other language like French using PHP with the help of update query I got a white page, means the query is not executed successfully. or an error like below.

When I update the content like this text
"Notre équipe de spécialistes saura vous accompagner tout au long des mandats dans un soucis constant d'efficacité."

I got an error like this : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'efficacité.
Nos experts ont oeuvré au sein de différentes agences p' at line 1"

I know this is problem of different encoding but I am failed to resolve this.

Some more strange thing also happen. I have my website at local Server, at demo subdomain and on Production server. The content for other language update is working on but on production website it is giving a blank page. means the query is not executed.

Please tell me fast how can I resolve this.

Comment: Tell us fast what your query is. [You have an error in your SQL syntax](http://www.jadito.us/2013/06/30/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax/)

Comment: You need to escape your values. Or better yet, to use bound parameters to avoid having apostrophes break your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an SQL injection vulnerability, and the `'` in `d'efficacité`  broke your query. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO people (names) VALUES ('Miles O'Brien');
                                   ^-- start of string
                                                 ^---supposed end of string
                                           ^--- actual end of string
```

The DB will interpret this as:

`Miles O` - the string to put into the names field
  `Brien` - some unknown SQL keyword/field name

You **MUST** properly escape all data going into your query, e.g.

```
   ... VALUES ('Miles O\'Brien');
                       ^--- escape
```

or better yet, use a better DB library that allows placeholders and/or prepared statements.

TL;DR: It's not an encoding problem.

Comment: By Placing a back slash(\) it working but as I have written the same content is updating without back slash on my demo sub domain.. can you tell me .. how this happeing

Comment: Is there any regular expression for this. Means whenever a '(single quote) found in the text it automatically insert a back slash .. is this possible.

and which better DB library I should use and how?

Comment: Older PHP versions have a terminally moronic "feature" called "magic quotes" that probably escaped the `'`-quote for you. It probably 'saved' you from seeing this bug. The fact remains, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You should NOT be working on database-related code until you know what the problem is and how to deal with it.